# Weeks in month June 2014

Tags: java, calendar, week-number

Sorry for asking daft question but I cannot get correct number of weeks in June 2014 returned by Calendar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out
        .println("first day of week: " + calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    System.out.println("weeks in month: "
        + calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println("days in month: "
        + calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

I am getting:

```
first day of week: 2
weeks in month: 5
days in month: 30
```

[image]

Why number of weeks in June 2014 is not 6? I am using jdk1.8.0_05 on Mac OS X 10.9.3.

Comment: I tried to create Calendar with Locale.UK also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of a week depends on what each `Locale` (country, region, whatever) defines as the first day of the week. You can check that with `Calendar#getFirstDayOfWeek()`. It also depends on what it considers the minimal days in the first week should be. You can get that with `Calendar#getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`. Your `Locale` seems to show that it needs more than one day to consider that period a week.

For example, with `Locale.CANADA`, I get 6 weeks since the `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` returns `1`.

Comment: It's the same if I do Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE); or Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK);

Comment: @ruruskyi Yes, because both of those require 4 days for a week.